# Get error with ExecuteNonQuery(). using SQL Server and ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to find out the way to figure out this problem. What I want is: if I click the submit button, the value that I enter will be transmitted to SQL Server.

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;

    namespace Comp
    {
        public partial class _Default : Page
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=Comp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123");

            protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [Students] value(@id,@lname,@fname,@date)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lnTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fnTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTextBox.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And the result is here:

```
Line 31:   con.Open();  
Line 32:   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [Students] value(@id,@lname,@fname,@date)", con);  
Line 33:   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idTextBox.Text);  // GET ERROR HERE  
Line 34:   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lnTextBox.Text);  
Line 35:   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fnTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: What's error? can you show images

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This query syntax may potentially wrong if the column names are not in proper order against actual table:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [Students] value(@id,@lname,@fname,@date)", con);
```

The proper standard syntax example should be like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert Into [Students] (ID, LName, FName, Date) 
                                  Values (@id, @lname, @fname, @date)", con);
```

If the `id` column is an autogenerated identity primary key column, it should be omitted from the statement:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert Into [Students] (LName, FName, Date) 
                                  Values (@lname, @fname, @date)", con);
```

Last, if the data type of `id` (and `date`) column is not defined as string (and `id` values are not autogenerated), conversion to corresponding data types are necessary:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert Into [Students] (ID, LName, FName, Date) 
                                  Values (@id, @lname, @fname, @date)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(idTextBox.Text)); // convert to integer first if 'id' column is integer
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lnTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fnTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Parse(dateTextBox.Text)); // example conversion if 'date' is DateTime
```

Or you can use `Parameters.Add` method and define proper [`SqlDbType` data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) like example below:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert Into [Students] (ID, LName, FName, Date) 
                                  Values (@id, @lname, @fname, @date)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(idTextBox.Text); // convert to integer first if 'id' column is integer
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lnTextBox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fnTextBox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(dateTextBox.Text); // example conversion if 'date' is DateTime
```

Comment: Thank you! it works for me!! One more question: Right now I have a table to show me the data from the sql server, so is it possible to transfer me or the user to the related page? For example: right now I have a list of names, if I click apple in this list, I will be transferred to fruit page. Of course, in the sql server, I have multiple tables, like the name of the list, and fruit table, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert string into `ID` column but `ID` data type is `int`
so change this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idTextBox.Text);
```

into this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.Int16(idTextBox.Text));
```

the `Date` column data type is datetime and you need to change this line

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTextBox.Text);
```

into this

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(dateTextBox.Text));
```